# Handling visual overflow in a tkinter frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a class that adds a scrolling frame. It detects when the frame's contents exceed its height, and then configures the scrollbar. The problem is that when I scroll down, the items in the frame scroll outside of the top of the frame and appear above it.

I've tested it out using plain labels, and it worked fine, but I'm using a class object that has some nested frames, and the child objects are what show up above the scrolling frame.

This is the gist of the code that's giving me problems (please note that the layout doesn't match the full project. I used [this](https://gist.github.com/mp035/9f2027c3ef9172264532fcd6262f3b01) as my reference for the `ScrollFrame()` class.)

Just running this, pressing the button, and scrolling down will show you what's wrong with it.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog as sd


class ScrollFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)


        ### setting up the objects used ###
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(master, orient = 'vertical',
                                      command = self.canvas.yview)


        ### scrollbar moves with current canvas scrollamount ###
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.scrollbar.set)


        self.scrollbar.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'y')
        self.canvas.pack(side = 'left', fill = 'both', expand = True)


        ### creating frame to pack widgets onto ###
        self.canvas.create_window((4, 4), window = self.frame,
                                  anchor = 'nw', tags = 'self.frame')


        ### setting scrollbar height on load ###
        self.frame.bind('<Configure>', self.frameConfig)


        ### scroll when a user's mouse wheel is used inside the canvas ###
        def scrollCanvas(event):
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1*(event.delta//120), 'units')
        self.canvas.bind('<MouseWheel>', scrollCanvas)


    ### set the scrollregion of the canvas ###
    def frameConfig(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox('all'))

class OptionSet(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):

        super().__init__()
        self.all = tk.Frame(master)
        self.all.configure(bd = 1, relief = 'solid')


        # independent label
        self.text = '' if not kwargs['text'] else kwargs['text']
        self.label = tk.Label(text = self.text)


        # list of all buttons
        self.buttons = tk.Frame()

        buttons = [] if not kwargs['buttons'] else kwargs['buttons']
        self.button_list = []

        if buttons:
            for button in buttons:
                self.button_list.append(
                        tk.Button(self.buttons, text = button)
                    )

        self.style()


    def style(self, default = 1, **kwargs):

        if default:
            self.label.pack(in_ = self.all, side = 'left')

            for button in self.button_list:
                button.pack(side = 'left')

            self.buttons.pack(in_ = self.all, side = 'right')


root = tk.Tk()

list_items = []
current = {
    'month': 'August'
    # ...
}

def btn_fcn(num):

        for i in list_items:
            i.grid_forget()

        '''
        # get event as input
        event = sd.askstring('Event Input',
            f"What is happening on {current['month']} {num}?")

        # insert new list_item
        list_items.append(OptionSet(event_list.frame, text = event,
                          buttons = ['Edit', 'Delete']))
        print(event)
        '''

        for i in range(10):
            list_items.append(OptionSet(event_list.frame, text = 'test',
                                        buttons = ['Edit', 'Delete']))

        for i in list_items:
            i.all.grid(sticky = 'we')

tk.Button(root, text = 'Add', command = lambda: btn_fcn(22)).pack()
event_list = ScrollFrame(root)
event_list.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I want the buttons and labels to cut off outside of the ScrollFrame. I don't know whether they're overflowing from the frame or the canvas, but they should cut off normally if all goes according to plan.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're being very sloppy with where you create your widgets. For example, you aren't putting the canvas and scrollbar in the ScrollFrame, you're putting it in `master`. Every widget defined in `ScrolLFrame` needs to be in `self` or a child of `self`.

The same is true with `OptionSet` - you're putting the inner frame (`self.all`) a d the other widgets in `master` rather than inside the `OptionSet` itself.

My recommendation is to temporarily remove all of the `OptionSet` code (or just don't use it) and instead, just add labels to the scroll frame. Focus on getting that working without the complexity of a custom class being added to a custom class.  Once you are able to scroll just labels, the you can add back in the `OptionSet` code.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I was able to solve the problem by making everything in both classes a child of ```self```, which I didn't know would work beforehand. Much appreciated!